# Can a single ballot be used to vote on several proposals?

Tags: roberts-rules-of-order

Our assembly of several hundred will be voting on 4 separate changes to our constitution. I would like the 4 votes to take place on a single ballot (one piece of paper with 4 proposals and corresponding yes/no check boxes) for efficiency's sake. Is this permissible under Robert's Rules of Order? Would we frame it as a single motion several sub-points, or 4 motions after which all are voted on at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Is it related to one correction to the constitution?  For example, the First Amendment of the United States Constitution is generally held to have 5 protections that are related (Free Speech, Freedom of Religion, Freedom of Assembly, Freedom of Association, Freedom of Press.  Note this is not ordered, nor covers all the nuances.  Just general list) but was voted on under one amendment.  The Swiss constitution marks theses same five protections under their own individual amendment, despite taking a large influence from the U.S. Constitution in terms of government system.

I would say if they are related to correcting similar problems, do it.  However if one is about how the President is elected, one is about how dues are collected, and two are about banning Hawaiian Pizza at all Pizza Parties, then seperate them according to what they change (and vote no on Hawaiian Pizza bans!).

A single ballot classically refers to a vote cast on one question to the voters and when a voter has multiple questions it is said they are casting ballots.  With the use of paper voting, a single sheet is often referred to as a ballot (and each question is a ballot measure).  Either way, it is perfectly fine that a single sheet has multiple questions that ask for vote on each measure.  You might pass the changes to the presidency and due collections, vote no on the first pizza issue and yes on second pizza issue (why?!).  Or some other combination.  Each question gets one vote for each individual but it would ease the casting of votes.  Ballots are also used in secret elections.

If this isn't secret elections, you can do voting out loud with Aye, Nay, Abstain (Call each member and have them announce their answers.  See the Congressional vote Talley in the film Lincoln for the Amendment they were passing).  This is largely used in a representative body where you're given a mandate from a particular constituency to vote them, like the House of Representatives or the Senate and thus you cannot vote in secret because you're being judged on your Representative abilities.

Voice Votes are basically the more legit equivalent of the "clap-o-meter" which isn't based on the individual tally but the loudness of the Ayes vs. the Nays (All in favor?  **AYE!**  All opposed? Nay.  The Ayes have it!).  This is largely done when the vote is so universally one-sided, it's really a formality at this point... but it has to be voted on cause rules is rules.   You see this a lot in Congress when either house is voting on an issue like "Giving Free American Flags to wounded vets on the Fourth of July".